# Autocomplete jQuery with phonegap on large results

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite, cordova, autocomplete

I need to add an autocomplete to a input field in my app using phonegap. I am aware of the autocomplete widget that jquery has and I wanted to use that in my app too. What I need is for the autocomplete to look for strings based off a query made in the sqlite db I have installed on my tablet.

```
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
     source: "script_that_queries_the_db.php"
});
```

From another thread I got this, but since phonegap doesn't use php, are we allowed to call a JS file similarly and make that query a function, for example

```
function getSitenames () { 
   //stuff in here to build an array to use by autocomplete 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: My JSON/Array I'll be grabbing from the database will contain around 1900 entries at a time. Since autocomplete will always recall the source, I was hoping to do something like

```
SELECT name FROM sitenames WHERE name LIKE ?
```

and parse in the `response.text` each time and build the array like that. (Since the sitesnames table holds 1900+ entries)

Comment: @CL. I've tried using the `.slice()` feature of arrays in javascript to break down the array, however, it is still a huge array and I still have to look through it (the array size is around 1900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So jQM doesn't support autocomplete properly, I had to use this, https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js for a substitution. It essentially works the same, where I used:

`source: function (text) {  var arrayClients = findCleints(text); callback(arrayClients) },`